# Show HTTP request duration in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Swagger UI has the [displayRequestDuration](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) parameter to show how long a request takes. It's disabled by default.

How can this be enabled in the SwaggerConfig.cs configuration when using [Swashbuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/) (the not-core version)?

I see this is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49564414/65545) in the Java version.

Comment: Hah - I've literally just run into the same problem. Fun to discover that it got asked 2 weeks prior!

Comment: Note that this has now been raised (by Bernard) as a FeatureRequest w/ the Swashbuckle team: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/1295

Comment: Note that the displayed request duration appears to include the render time and can be several hundred ms longer than the request duration shown in your browser's dev tools for large responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In recent versions you can do

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(
    settings => settings.AdditionalSettings.Add("displayRequestDuration ", true));
)
```

since `app.UseSwaggerUI` is marked as obsolete.

Tested with .NET Core 3.x.

Answer (score 16):

According to the [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/), this is a Swagger UI configuration.  For my .Net Core app, I was able to get the **Request duration** with the following code.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.DisplayRequestDuration();
        // .... other configurations
    });
```

[image: Example for the Request Duration]

Comment: This must the right answer in the current trend with respect to latest framework and version. Must be voted on top